# Adding a facebook page tab using php

Tags: php, facebook-page

I have created a facebook application and a facebook page.
Using js sdk i have collected the access token for the page 
Now I want to add a page tab using php code  in the page.

Not getting any idea how to do this

Does any one have an idea about this

Comment: Maybe this answer that I have a couple of hours ago will help you out... http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/a/9062105/558021.  You should search first before asking a new question - perhaps someone else has been having the same problem as you...

Answer (score 4):

You can do this with PHP-SDK like this (see details in [documentation for `tabs` connection `page` object](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/#tabs)):

```
$facebook->api('/PAGE_ID/tabs', 'POST', array(
  'app_id'=>'APP_ID',
  'access_token'=>'PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN'
));
```

Comment: To see more ways to do this you can also read my answer for [How to add tab application to a page with the “new auth dialog”](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/a/8596312/155033)

Comment: hi.. why it does not work for me? it gives the error (#210) Subject must be a page.

Answer (score 2):

simple steps :)

1.verify that you complete page tab settings in your app settings [link](https://developers.facebook.com/apps)

2.make sure your page tab app should be 520px

3.now you just need to forward browser to this below address so user can select with page he/she want to add tab  `https://www.facebook.com/dialog/pagetab?app_id=YOUR_APP_ID&next=YOUR_URL`

you can also read the above points in detail [here is link of fb doc](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/appsonfacebook/pagetabs/)

Comment: hi if you need any more help from me please contact me now because i will be offline for few hours after almost 10 minutes  :)

and yes when you done let me known your fb app url so i will also use this :)

Comment: Hi danish i am not so clear on this how to do this , i just want to add a facebook tab in my page , so can you give me ur contact info , to discuss on this clearly

Comment: @RohitPuroHit 1. [go to this link](https://developers.facebook.com/apps) and give me your app id and your app url
and i dont known giving contacts details is allow or not

Comment: Hi danish , i tried it using 3 step , but it is saying that "This application does not support integration with your profile." Can you suggest how to do this

Comment: @RohitPuroHit
try using this url 
     http://facebook.com/add.php?api_key=YOUR_APP_KEY&pages=1&page=YOUR_PAGE_ID
and if this yet not solved your problem give me your app id so that i check this personally :)

Comment: this one is opening a page which asks for adding the page to application but i want to add tabs in multiple pages from one application , please give me ur contact info so i can contact you and explain clearly

Answer (score 1):

You can add an app to a page by redirecting user to:

```
http://www.facebook.com/dialog/pagetab?app_id=YOUR_APP_ID&next=YOUR_URL
```

Reference: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/appsonfacebook/pagetabs/